# Is there a naming convention for enum values that have a leading digit?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a c# enumeration that looks like this:

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed {

    [Description("10BASE-T")]
    _10BaseT,

    [Description("100BASE-T")]
    _100BaseT,

    [Description("1000BASE-T")]
    _1000BaseT,

    [Description("Disconnected")]
    Disconnected
}
```

I added a leading underscore to each value to make the compiler happy.

Is there a standard naming convention for enumerations like this?  The underscore I've used doesn't seem like the best choice.

Comment: If the actual eNum isn't being exposed to a public view then who cares what it is called as long as the code works!

Comment: @Peter M: Other developers who have to maintain the code later on. And btw: "public enum EthernetLinkSpeed" means that the enum is visible to a public view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know of no convention, but how about

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed {
 Link10BaseT, Link1000BaseT, LinkDisconnected
}
```

Comment: +1 In C and in linux, serial port enumerations use this kind of prefix (sometimes shorter): Baud rates are named Bxxxxx where xxxxx is the (integer constant) speed: B9600 is a 9600 baud rate. Anyway, the idea is the same: a short prefix that helps identify the content.

Comment: I selected this suggestion as the answer for my particular example, however the general consensus seems to be that a standard prefix of some sort is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I just look for something more descriptive in this case. For instance, since you have a "Disconnected" enum value, I would use something like:

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed {
    Connected10BaseT,
    Connected100BaseT,
    Connected1000BaseT,
    Disconnected
}
```

Since these are compile-time only, there's no damage in having them as long you like, even if making them long just means making them descriptive enough to pass the compiler's naming rules.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but the built-in [`NetworkInterfaceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype.aspx) enum includes the following values:

> ```
> Ethernet, Ethernet3Megabit, FastEthernetT, FastEthernetFx, GigabitEthernet
> ```

It's a bit ugly for my liking, but I might consider using an `Ethernet` prefix for your enum:

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed
{
    [Description("10BASE-T")]
    Ethernet10BaseT,

    [Description("100BASE-T")]
    Ethernet100BaseT,

    [Description("1000BASE-T")]
    Ethernet1000BaseT,

    [Description("Disconnected")]
    Disconnected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a convention, but something like this may be subjectively less 'ugly':

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed {

    [Description("10BASE-T")]
    TenBaseT,

    [Description("100BASE-T")]
    OneHundredBaseT,

    [Description("1000BASE-T")]
    OneThousandBaseT,

    [Description("Disconnected")]
    Disconnected
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We usually prefix them with 'e'

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed
{
    e10BaseT,
    e100BaseT,
    e1000BaseT,
    Disconnected
}
```

We deal with a lot of video resolutions, 720p etc, so we use e720p.  In your case, I think using the names may be better, Ethernet, FastEthernet, and GigabitEthernet.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, names are important.  So, sometimes it's good to explore non-obvious alternatives.

A completely different alternative:

```
public enum EthernetLinkSpeed {

  [Description("10BASE-T")]
  MegabitSlow,

  [Description("100BASE-T")]
  MegabitFast,

  [Description("1000BASE-T")]
  Gigabit,

  [Description("Disconnected")]
  Disconnected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It never hurts to add a unique prefix to all the related enums. If nothing else, it helps with search/replace editing of your source code down the road.